# GoDaddy shared hosting get process id

Tags: php, kill-process

I have a GoDaddy shared hosting and I'm running this PHP code that works fine:

```
exec('../node/bin/node node_app.js "message" ', $output);
```

I'm running it in a loop, so at a certain time (iteration) it shows an error saying that the allowed memory size is exhausted. I think that the solution is to kill the process in every iteration in the loop but I cannot find the process id to kill it even if I add `&` in the `exec` function and `print_r` output it doesn't show me the process id.

this is the loop code if it can help

```
function fok($i,$maxID){
if($i <= $maxID){
    $elem = R::load('elem',$i);
    if($elem->id != 0){
        $row = R::dispense('row');
        exec('../node/bin/node node_app.js "'.$elem->text.'" ', $output);
        $row->text = $output;
        R::store($row);
    }
    fok($i+1,$maxID);
}
}
fok(1,20000);
```

Comment: *"so at a certain time it shows an error saying that the allowed memory size is exhausted."* - for example, at 10:00pm or at iteration *x*?

Comment: at iteration x in my case it's 14456

Comment: Can you paste the PHP error detailing the memory size is exhausted?

Comment: it happened yesterday and it take about 2 hours after executing the script it gives something like that "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate x bytes)" x is a big number